# Count instances based on criteria with groupby()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [60]: df1
Out[60]: 
    DIFF  UID
0    NaN    1
1   13.0    1
2    4.0    1
3    NaN    2
4    3.0    2
5   23.0    2
6    NaN    3
7    4.0    3
8   29.0    3
9   42.0    3
10   NaN    4
11   3.0    4
```

and for each `UID` I want to calculate how many instances are found to have a value for `DIFF` over a given param.

I have tried something like this:

```
In [61]: threshold = 5

In [62]: df1[df1.DIFF > threshold].groupby('UID')['DIFF'].count().reset_index().rename(columns={'DIFF':'ATTR_NAME'})
Out[63]: 
   UID  ATTR_NAME
0    1          1
1    2          1
2    3          2
```

That works fine, in regards to finding the returning the right count of instances per user etc. However, I would like to be able to also include the users that have 0 instances, which are now excluded in the `df1[df1.DIFF > threshold]` part.

The desired output would be:

```
   UID  ATTR_NAME
0    1          1
1    2          1
2    3          2
3    4          0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use [`.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
req = df1[df1.DIFF > threshold].groupby('UID')['DIFF'].count()
req = req.reindex(df1.UID.unique()).reset_index().rename(columns={'DIFF':'ATTR_NAME'})
```

---

In one line:

```
df1[df1.DIFF > threshold].groupby('UID')['DIFF'].count().reindex(df1.UID.unique()).reset_index().rename(columns={'DIFF':'ATTR_NAME'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I need to learn how to use `reindex` better.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use a function with `apply()` to do this:

```
In [101]: def count_instances(x, threshold):
    counter = 0
    for i in x:
        if i > threshold: counter += 1
    return counter
   .....: 

In [102]: df1.groupby('UID')['DIFF'].apply(lambda x: count_instances(x, 5)).reset_index()
Out[102]: 
   UID  DIFF
0    1     1
1    2     1
2    3     2
3    4     0
```

It appears that this way is a little faster as well:

```
In [103]: %timeit df1.groupby('UID')['DIFF'].apply(lambda x: count_instances(x, 5)).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.38 ms per loop

In [104]: %timeit df1[df1.DIFF > 5].groupby('UID')['DIFF'].count().reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.39 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work well for you?

[image]

Comment: This is a good one. Seems to be a little slower than the previous two suggestions though. Thanks for the help! `In [109]: %timeit df1.groupby('UID')['DIFF'].agg({'count': lambda x: (x > 5).sum()}).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.08 ms per loop`

Comment: Try to copy and paste your code, instead of using a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Searching to count the numbers of values matching criteria without filtering out the keys that have no matches is equivalent to counting the numbers of `True` matches per group, which can be done with a `sum` of boolean values:

```
(df1.DIFF > 5).groupby(df1.UID).sum().reset_index()

   UID  DIFF
0    1   1.0
1    2   1.0
2    3   2.0
3    4   0.0
```